# How to map a object of a POJO class to json type of Posgres

Tags: java, json, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

There is a custom class

```
class MyClass {
   private UUID id;
   private MyJsonType jsonType;
 }

class MyJsonType {
    private UUID id;
    private Status status;
}

enum Status {
   ACTIVE, COMPLETED, ARCHIVE;
}
```

by calling

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(1, new MyJsonType(1, ACTIVE));
myClassRepository.save(myClass)
```

jsonType field should be saved in db as json type of Postgres

Comment: you mena, you want json formatted data in your db? Moreover, did you declared constructor for MyJsonType?

Comment: when I save an object of pojo class it should be mapped in db to type of json

Comment: any problem you faced in any particular way or the way you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article about this: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/